# Need to have RDP to more than six machine concurrently in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, server, rdp

I need to have RDP in windows server 2016 for six different machine concurrently for development purpose in my company . But currently it supports only two machine concurrently for RDP .

What steps do I need to follow to have the above scenario .?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the amount of allowed incoming rdp connections, you will need to change the group policy.

1. Connect to the Windows Server machine
2. Right click on the Start button, and select Run
3. enter "gpedit.msc" and click OK
4. In the left hand side of the "Local Group Policy Editor", navigate to
   Computer
       Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >
       Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections.
5. On the right hand side find this setting: **Restrict Remote Desktop
       Services user to a single Remote Desktop Services session**, and
       switch it to disabled
6. In the same right hand side list, find this
       setting: **Limit number of connections** and set that to a specific
       number of connections you want.